# Android Action Bar title disappears after populating custom ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, rss

**My problem is:** Upon launching the app, with only one activity, the Action Bar correctly displays the application title "ParseC" (while the content area is still blank), but after loading a RSS and populating a custom listview, the title disappears. This was tested on API 16 and 23 with same effect.

onCreate() parses a RSS feed; when it's done, onPostExecute populates the list view with the entries, and at this moment the app bar title disappears. 
If I run getSupportActionBar().getTitle().toString(), I do get the correct answer (ParseC).

This is my MainActivity.java (onCreate):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    context = this;

    new DownloadXmlTask().execute(URL);
}
```

and (onPostExecute):

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Adapter code
    ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    // get data from the table by the ListAdapter
    ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(context, R.layout.itemlistrow, theEntries);
    yourListView .setAdapter(customAdapter);
}
```

**What I expected** was for the title to stay there, since I did not leave the activity (I suspect the error might be happening on the layouts).

As for the layouts, the main activity layout (activity_main.xml) includes content_main.xml, which has the listview which uses the custom layout itemlistrow.xml.

**My question is:** What could be causing the App Bar label to be hidden?

AndroidManifest.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="co.samoliver.parsec">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="co.samoliver.parsec.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />
```

Layouts:
content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="co.samoliver.parsec.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
```

itemlistrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<TextView android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title" android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:height="40sp"
    android:textSize="16dp" />


<TextView android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/summary"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Summary"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:height="20sp"
    android:typeface="normal" />

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:gravity="right"
android:id="@+id/id"
android:text="Id"
android:height="0sp"
android:typeface="normal" />
```

Comment: If you suspect the error might be happening on the layouts, then post the layouts please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error could be in your manifest `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`. Also, you do not need to call `setContentView()` twice (this may also be contributing to your problem). Once in the `onCreate()` should do. It will increase your app's performance if you do not call it twice and instead call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter when the data is received. I would recommend setting your adapter in the `onCreate()` itself and when the data is received just update it.

Comment: Thank you. My specific problem was the setContentView() being called the second time (I would like to understand why). I kept the adapter on postexecute, because putting it earlier gave me a null pointer exception.

Comment: `setContentView()` will explicitly take the view hierarchy and replace it with the view given. Therefore, all the work you have done with the actionbar will be lost. For the null pointer, are you creating the adapter in `onCreate()` and maybe making it an instance variable? That would probably be more efficient and accessible to the activity when needed. The null pointer could also be connected to using `setContentView()` twice.